# SSL handshake does not work on docker container

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose

I need to call one resource on `docker` container which require `L2TP/IPsec VPN`. VPN setup is OK (I am getting 200 status code response while calling it directly from my laptop). But then I do it from the docker container connection gets stuck on `ssl handshake.`

How should I setup the docker so container so behavior would be the same as in my laptop?

**Python traceback**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sp/server/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/sp/server/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 844, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/sp/server/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/sp/server/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 324, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 817, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
socket.timeout: _ssl.c:835: The handshake operation timed out
```

**dockerfiles/ServerDockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.6-jessie

RUN pip install virtualenv

ADD . /sp
WORKDIR /sp/server

# Register api port
EXPOSE 8090

CMD make run
```

**docker-compose.yml** :

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/ServerDockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/sp
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
```

I tried to call that same resource from other `docker` containers i have on my computer and it is always the same situation - stuck on `ssl` handshake.

Answer (score 4):

I solved my issue by setting `docker-compose.yml` [network_mode](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode) parameter value to `host`.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/ServerDockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/sp  # mount repo dir to container for development
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    network_mode: "host"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to run

```
docker logs <container name> -f
```

and capture what the output from the attempted SSL handshake is?

You probably need a SSL cert in your container to connect to a server with SSL.  You can either add the cert to your image from with your Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
COPY target/app.jar /opt/spring-cloud/lib/
COPY certs/ssl.cer $JAVA_HOME/lib/security
RUN \
  cd $JAVA_HOME/lib/security \
  && keytool -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -trustcacerts -importcert -alias edlscert -file edls.cer
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/java"]
CMD ["-jar", "/opt/spring-cloud/lib/app.jar"]
VOLUME /var/lib/spring-cloud/config-repo
EXPOSE 9101
```

There are limitations to this approach, however, and a better solution is probably to provide the .cer at deployment time as part of the docker-compose file.  Regardless, you'll need a certificate to communicate to an outside service over SSL/HTTPS.

Comment: Output from the handshake - I think that python traceback is the best i've got. Server log for reference:
`GET /api/authentication/login?session_state=............" 500 7846
2019-01-17 07:36:01,369 root         INFO     ReqId: None SessionId: None Received authorization code response
2019-01-17 07:36:01,370 root         INFO     ReqId: None SessionId: None Sending access token request
2019-01-17 07:36:01,371 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool DEBUG    ReqId: None SessionId: None Starting new HTTPS connection (1): auth.****.org`

Comment: Glad that the logs were helpful.  I'm not a python guru, so I would take that output and try google.  I'm sorry I can't offer further assistance.  Did you add the certificate to your image or container?

Comment: Look at the answer below. I set network_mode to "host" on docker-compose, solved everything :)  I tried to setup vpn before that on my docker container (certificate was not enough in my case because it is l2tp) almost successfully  with this https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn/blob/master/docs/clients.md#configure-linux-vpn-clients-using-the-command-line but it is way to much work..\